# How can I calculate the standard deviation knowing an event probability and a number of trials?

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation

I'm writing a test for a probabilistic data structure that I've implemented. Since its probabilistic, its performance is different every time, and in particular, the performance varies much more widely (as a percentage) when the number of items is small. I want the test to fail if the performance is so bad that it's unlikely to have been that bad by chance. Basically, I want a significance test.

In the test, I check the structure n times. Each check may fail with probability p. If the total number of failures is more than twice the standard deviation greater than the mean (n*p), I want to fail the test. Now, I know n and I can calculate p. How can I use n and p to get the standard deviation?

I know it can be easily estimated by simulation, but there are about a hundred combinations of n and p, so I would prefer a way to just calculate it. Unfortunately, I haven't found an answer, or if I have it was too complex for this layman to notice.

Comment: When you say "the total number of failures is greater than twice the standard deviation..." you should probably add "...more than the expected number of failures $np$..."

Comment: Good question!  I hope it's okay that I removed the "probability-theory" tag.

Comment: Thanks, Henry. It was poorly phrased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

If you know $p$ before the test and the checks are independent then the standard deviation is $\sqrt{ n p (1-p)}$

Comment: Excellent. This does indeed agree with my simulations. Thank you!

Comment: Similarly to calculate mean we simply multiply p and n.